# InvalidOperationException with FirebaseFirestore in Unity: Cannot Modify Settings After Instance Use

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-firestore

**Context**

**Platform**: Unity

**Related Libraries**: FirebaseFirestore

**Issue**
I am working on a Unity project and using FirebaseFirestore for database operations. Recently time to time I am encountering an InvalidOperationException with the following error message:

```
InvalidOperationException: The settings cannot be modified after calling non-static methods in the FirebaseFirestore instance or after the FirebaseFirestore instance is disposed.
```

This error occurs at line "firestore.Settings.PersistenceEnabled = false;" in my code.

```
private async void Start()
{

    var dependencyResult = await FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync();

    if(dependencyResult == DependencyStatus.Available)
    {
        _app = FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance;
        FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.DefaultInstance;
        firestore.Settings.PersistenceEnabled = false;

        OnFirebaseInitialized.Invoke();
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.LogError("Failed to initialize Firebase with reason: " + dependencyResult);
    }
}
```

Error started popping up since I repicked up this project after some time. I thought I should just update the libraries but I didn't see any advise in the update log about this error.

Comment: `Invoking any non-static method on this FirebaseFirestore instance will "lock in" the settings. No changes are allowed to be made to the settings once they are locked in. Attempting to do so will result in an exception being thrown by the property setter.` .. maybe this already happens at some point before to the default instance ...

Comment: thats strange since this is the only firebase code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug, please [file an issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-unity-sdk/issues/new/choose) with the Unity SDK to get the Firestore team's eyes on this.